# Border bottom below menu is not occupying the full width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I want to have a menu with some items, each item should have a border at right, and also there should be a border-bottom but occupying the full width. The issue is that the border bottom is only occupying the container with, not the full width. The container class should be necessary because the categories text should only occupy the container width.

Also when the user hovers each item it should appear a border-bottom below the item, and its working, the issue is that when the user hovers each item the item text moves a little bit, do you know why?

Do you know how to solve these issues?

The code with the issues: http://jsfiddle.net/pjgt1q35/

HTML

```
<div class="jumbotron p-0 m-0">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row align-items-center">
      <div class="col-7">
        <h1 class="display-5 font-weight-bold text-dark">Title</h1>
        <p class="lead text-light">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Incidunt voluptatum consequatur deserunt vel dicta voluptatibus sit asperiores minus dolore quidem assumenda amet officiis sequi facere harum accusamus, possimus omnis reiciendis.</p>
      </div>

      <div class="col-5">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/490" width="490" height="300">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="col p-0 m-0">
    <ul class="categories_menu">
      <li class="list-item--hidden">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" name="category" id="">Item 1</a>
      </li>
      <li class="list-item--hidden">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" name="category" id="">Item 2</a>
      </li>
      <li class="list-item--hidden">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" name="category" id="">Item 3</a>
      </li>
      <li class="list-item--hidden">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" name="category" id="">Item 4</a>
      </li>
      <li class="list-item--hidden">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" name="category" id="">Item 5</a>
      </li>
      <li><a data-toggle="modal" id="" data-target="" href="">More
        <i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
    </ul>

  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.categories_menu {
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  -moz-box-pack: justify;
  -ms-flex-pack: justify;
  justify-content: space-between;
  transition: all 100ms ease-out;

  li {
    -moz-box-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    border-bottom: 5px solid transparent;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -moz-box-flex: 1;
    -ms-flex: 1 1 auto;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    height: 59px;
    -moz-box-pack: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    justify-content: center;
    padding: 10px 0 5px 0;
    border-left: 1px solid red;
    border-bottom: 1px solid red;

    &:first-child {
      border-left: 0;
    }

    &:hover {
      border-bottom: 5px solid red;
      color: #000;
      cursor: pointer;
      text-decoration: none
    }
    a {
      color: #414e5f;
      font-size: 18px;
      font-weight: bold;
    }
    &.active {
      border-bottom: 5px solid red;

    }

  }
}
```

Comment: The full width of what? The entire menu?

Comment: The full with of the page, the issue should because the categories_menu is inside the .container, however the categories items should occupy only the .container width.

Comment: Are you able to use .container-flex instead of .container?

Comment: [Adding border on hover moves element and shifts surrounding elements](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40556669/3597276)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make full width container you can use `container-flex` instead of `container`.
Create a `row` inside the container and put the `col` there.

```
<div class="container-flex">
<div class="menu-row row">
<div class="col p-0 m-0">
    <ul class="categories_menu">
      <li class="list-item--hidden">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" name="category" id="">Item 1</a>
      </li>
      <li class="list-item--hidden">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" name="category" id="">Item 2</a>
      </li>
      <li class="list-item--hidden">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" name="category" id="">Item 3</a>
      </li>
      <li class="list-item--hidden">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" name="category" id="">Item 4</a>
      </li>
      <li class="list-item--hidden">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" name="category" id="">Item 5</a>
      </li>
      <li><a data-toggle="modal" id="" data-target="" href="">More
        <i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
    </ul>

  </div>
</div>
```

And use this style:

```
.menu-row {
    border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}
.menu-row ul {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

To avoid problem with moving hover `<li>`, use this style:

```
a {
    color: #414e5f;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
    border-bottom: 5px solid transparent;
}
&.active {
    border-bottom: 5px solid red;

}
```

```css
.categories_menu {
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  -moz-box-pack: justify;
  -ms-flex-pack: justify;
  justify-content: space-between;
  transition: all 100ms ease-out;
}

li {
    -moz-box-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    border-bottom: 5px solid transparent;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -moz-box-flex: 1;
    -ms-flex: 1 1 auto;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    height: 59px;
    -moz-box-pack: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    justify-content: center;
    padding: 10px 0 5px 0;
    border-left: 1px solid red;
}

    li:first-child {
      border-left: 0;
    }

    li:hover {
      border-bottom: 5px solid red;
      color: #000;
      cursor: pointer;
      text-decoration: none
    }
    a {
      color: #414e5f;
      font-size: 18px;
      font-weight: bold;
      border-bottom: 5px solid transparent;
    }
    &.active {
      border-bottom: 5px solid red;

    }

.menu-row {
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}
    
.menu-row ul {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>

    <div class="container-flex">
    <div class="menu-row row">
    <div class="col p-0 m-0">
        <ul class="categories_menu">
          <li class="list-item--hidden">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" name="category" id="">Item 1</a>
          </li>
          <li class="list-item--hidden">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" name="category" id="">Item 2</a>
          </li>
          <li class="list-item--hidden">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" name="category" id="">Item 3</a>
          </li>
          <li class="list-item--hidden">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" name="category" id="">Item 4</a>
          </li>
          <li class="list-item--hidden">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" name="category" id="">Item 5</a>
          </li>
          <li><a data-toggle="modal" id="" data-target="" href="">More
            <i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks it works the full width, but the moving hover issue is not working.

Comment: @user10676579 I added a code snippet to my answer, please, check it.

Comment: @user10676579 the only problem left: the first item in the menu has not proper hover bottom border width

Comment: Thanks, can you explain better that issue of the first item? I didnt understand.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I saw your comment above. 
Can you create a new div?

```
<div class="bottom-bordered-div">
    ....your entire code starting with the containing container div
</div>
```

Just give it a bottom border and it is wrapping your container so your menu is still in the container width.

Answer (score 0):

There is padding to the left of menu

```
.categories_menu {
    padding-left:0;
}
```

The reason the menu item moves when you hover, is because you have the following

Hover

```
border-bottom: 5px solid red
```

Non-hover

```
border-bottom: 1px solid red;
```

There are 4px of space between hover and non-hover, so the item will move 4px down when hovering.

You should add border to the `<a>` when hovering instead of the `<li>`